# File not being sent

Tags: github-actions

I am trying to zip build files and send it to our server.

They all say they completed fine, but I can't find the zip file on the actual server.

I can't even figure out if this means the zip file wasn't created, or if it wasn't sent.

Please let me know what and how I can check.

```js
  - name: Generate deployment package
    run: zip -r devServer.zip . -x '*.git*' './src/*' './node_modules/*'

  - name: Deploy build outputs
    uses: appleboy/scp-action@master
    with:
      host: ${{ secrets.REMOTE_IP }}
      username: ${{ secrets.REMOTE_SSH_ID }}
      key: ${{ secrets.REMOTE_SSH_KEY }}
      source: "devServer.zip"
      strip_components: 1
      target: "/home/ubuntu"
```

22 port is open.

Below is the action for the deploy part.

```js
tar all files into /tmp/sRWFsGKD.tar.gz
23
remote server os type is unix
24
scp file to server.
25
create folder /home/***
26
untar file sRWFsGKD.tar.gz
27
remove file sRWFsGKD.tar.gz
```

Also, when I tried a different path for source, I got the error:

> tar: empty archive

so it looks like `scp` is the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve it as shown below.

I used `tar` instead of `zip`.

```yaml
  - name: Run a multi-line script
    run: |
      mkdir ../build
      cp -TR . ../build
      tar -cvf devServer.tar ../build/dist/

  - name: Deploy build outputs
    uses: appleboy/scp-action@master
    with:
      host: ${{ secrets.REMOTE_IP }}
      username: ${{ secrets.REMOTE_SSH_ID }}
      key: ${{ secrets.REMOTE_SSH_KEY }}
      port: ${{ secrets.REMOTE_SSH_PORT }}
      source: "devServer.tar"
      target: "myLocation"
```